# Get Spring Environment as Properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-environment

I wonder if there is a way to extract properties from Spring Environment (e.g. obtained from ApplicationContext) in the form of Properties instance? Or, at least, is there a way to enumerate the properties in Spring Environment, or get them all as a map, or any other way I can turn a [initially unknown] set of properties into a Properties object?

I need this in order to create a jclouds `Context` by calling `org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.newBuilder()` and `.overrides(Properties)`. The idea is to configure the actual cloud provider solely by means of .properties file, and I don't want to couple application logic with provider-specific properties.

**[UPDATE]**

The .properties files to be used are configured using `<context:property-placeholder>`, and it actually specifies a list of paths, like this:

```
< context:property-placeholder location=
    "classpath:/jdbc.properties,
    file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/jdbc.properties,
    file:${catalina.home}/conf/jdbc.properties"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

which suggests that the .properties file is searched in the mentioned list of locations in order. I would like to achieve the following:

- keep the list of .properties files and their possible locations in this XML definition file only;
- allow to place jclouds related properties in *any* of the .properties files mentioned in the XML;
- access the properties, resolved and loaded by Spring, in the form of Properties object so I am able to feed that to jclouds `ContextBuilder`.

Please let me know if all of this is feasible. Thank you in advance!

-Vlad

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to use properties in your Spring configuration then you can simply use:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />
```

To get the properties in your code later you can simply read this file from the classpath into a Properties object:

```
props.load(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties"));
```

Alternatively you can have a look at  [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/).

**UPDATE**

Updated after Deinum's remark but only if you are getting the properties from a Spring managed bean:

```
<util:properties id="myProps" 
           location="classpath:foo.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="myProps" />
```

Now you can inject myProps into Spring managed beans (no need to load them again from the classpath).

Comment: Why so "complex". You can simply use `<util:properties />` to read the properties which in turn can also be injected into the `<context:property-placeholder />` element. Saves you loading the file twice.

Comment: Deinum, you are right but that will only work from Spring managed beans. Since the OP seems to be creating this object himself (newBuilder()) this will not work.

Comment: He needs properties those should be injected, how they are read shouldn't matter. The reading should be, imho, externalized.

Comment: How will he inject them in an Object he created himself? I did not make the assumption that he is doing this from a Spring managed bean. What is not externalized in my answer?

Comment: @M.Deinum, is it possible to specify a list of locations to `<util:properties />`?

Comment: @StijnGeukens You are right that that is external too I was looking only on how to obtain the `Properties` object so that it can be passed to the `override` method. I would probably create some kind of factory for the creation of the context object so that it is nicely abstracted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PropertiesFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html) and do something like this:

```
<bean id="jcloudsProps" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location">
    <value>your/props/file.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

You can then use `jcloudsProps` as you would any other Spring bean.

Comment: is it possible to refer this bean to existing `<util:properties/>` element? also, is that true that you can specify more than one value for location?